# How can I read a variable in bash, with the type specified like in C's scanf?

Tags: bash, terminal, scanf

How do I look for user input from the keyboard in the bash shell? I was thinking this would just work,

```
int b;

scanf("%d", &b);
```

but it says

> -bash: /Users/[name]/.bash_profile: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `"%d",'
>
> -bash: /Users/[name]/.bash_profile: line 17: `scanf("%d", &b);'

**EDIT**

```
backdoor() {
   printf "\nAccess backdoor Mr. Fletcher?\n\n"
   read -r b
   if (( b == 1 )) ; then
     printf "\nAccessing backdoor...\n\n"
   fi   
}
```

Comment: I'm curious -- what documentation or other context lead to trying to use a C library function in a shell script?

Comment: I am a noob programmer, I started by learning LUA, left it for like a year, then started to learn C, and then just today started to try to learn the bash stuff.

Comment: You don't need to declare your variables, either -- the `int b` can just be left out, as can the semicolons at endlines. I'd suggest starting from scratch with something like http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide rather than assuming that syntax from completely different languages will work for bash.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy re "What context lead to trying to use a C library function in a shell script?": Well, there *is* a `printf` builtin!

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, ...and it differs from the C one in critical ways (such as *not* requiring the number of placeholders and the number of arguments to match and doing a bunch of automatic conversions -- and that's before we get into new format specifiers such as `%b`, `%q` and `%(...)T`). If you tried valid usage from the bash `printf` in C, you'd soon end up with either compile-time warnings/errors or security bugs.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes of course. I was just outlining a possible train of thought which might lead to the asumption that there is a `scanf` in bash. In fact, I came to this very page because I googled "bash scanf"; I am trying to parse a string with a minimal set of sub-processes. There sure is a host of even bash-built-in string manipulation functions which can be used instead of a `scanf`. It's also not quite clear how one would realize the by-reference semantics of `scanf` target variables. But still: A `printf` without a `scanf` is an obvious asymmetry :-).

Answer (score 8):

Just use the `read` builtin:

```
read -r b
```

No need to specify type (as per `%d`), as variables aren't typed in shell scripts unless you jump through (needless) hoops to make them so; if you want to use a value as a decimal, that's a question of the context in which it's evaluated, not the manner in which it's read or stored.

For instance:

```
(( b == 1 ))
```

...treats `$b` as a decimal, whereas

```
[[ $b = 1 ]]
```

...does a *string comparison* between b and `"1"`.

Comment: Why does that not work? READ MY EDIT It says unexpected } at line 19 (the last line)

Comment: @Nightlock32 Code examples should be taken _exactly_ as given: `(( b == 1 ))`, not `(b == 1)` -- it takes _two_ parens to get bash into math context.

Comment: @Nightlock32 If that still didn't work, you'd want to be sure you were running this with bash in particular, not sh; sh is only guaranteed to support `$(( ))`, not `(( ))` (but then, a sh without `(( ))` typically won't support `[[ ]]` either).

Answer (score 2):

While you can declare variables as integers in Bash, the results won't do what you expect. A non-integer value will be converted to zero, which is probably not what you want. Here is a more bullet-proof way to ensure you gather an integer:

```
while read -p "Enter integer: " integer; do
    [[ "$integer" =~ [[:digit:]]+ ]] && break
    echo "Not an integer: $integer" >&2
done
```

This is particularly useful when you want to inform the user *why* a value is rejected, rather than just re-prompting.

Comment: Right now you're only checking that there's an integer *anywhere in* the string. If you want to be sure it consists *only* of integers, you need to anchor it: `^[[:digit:]]+$`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to mix C-like syntax with Bash syntax.

```
backdoor() {

    printf '\n%s\n\n' 'Access backdoor Mr. Fletcher?'

    read -r b

    if ((b == 1))
    then
        printf '\n%s\n\n' 'Accessing backdoor...'
    fi
}
```